# User input as a command line argument

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a program BIL.exe that prompts for user four inputs (marked with pink below).
[image]

I would like to run this program from command line by specifying the inputs as arguments. Something like this:

```
.\BIL.exe "HOAL" 78 80 1
```

In a batch script I can do it as shown below. However this doesn't work in command line.

```
@echo off
set var1="HOAL"
set var2=78
set var3=80
set var4=1  
(echo %var1% && echo %var2% && echo %var3% && echo %var4%)|BIL.exe
```

Does the solution differ between CMD and powershell?

Comment: maybe `set "var1=%~1"` and `set  "var2=%~2"` then run `test.bat "asdf" 1234`

Comment: The script is just illustrational. I cannot change how my actual program (exe) takes in input.

Comment: I suggest you show the actual usage of your executable. Some executables does not accept input from stdin, so be clear on what you're actually doing.

Comment: Added print screen of the actual usage of the executable. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Try adding some lines in list form to a file let's say `test.txt`  `"HOAL"` next line `78` then `80` etc. Then do `bill.exe<test.txt` if that does not work, then they did not create the program to accept stdin. If it does however work, i can create you a proper answer.

Comment: Tried it and it works in CMD (not in PS).

Comment: But you asked about batch, not powershell?

Comment: In `ps` you can do similar with `Get-Content test.txt | ./bill.exe` but will have to iterate each line.

Comment: I was not complaining, just stating an observation. I use both CMD and PS.

Comment: Ok. So would you like me to create an answer as a batch solution? Or are you happy to use the file as is?

Comment: Would be grateful for a batch solution.

Comment: Give me a few minutes. Just driving home, posted comments from my mobile.

Comment: Of the six batch file lines you've posted, five of them have issues, `2.` `set "var1=HOAL"`, `3.` `set "var2=78"`, `4.` `set "var3=80"`, `5.` `set "var4=1"`, `6.` `(echo "%var1%"& echo %var2%& echo %var3%& echo %var4%)| "BIL.exe"`. The way you've posted it `BIL.exe` would have received four responses ```"HOAL" ```, ```78 ```, ```80 ```, ```1   ```, note all of those trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So given your confirmation that stdin from file worked means that the solution should be simple:

**batch_name.cmd**

```
@echo off
(echo %1&echo %2&echo %3&echo %4)|bil.exe
```

it sends the output in list format. so you should be able to run the batch as:

```
batch_name.cmd "HOAL" 78 80 1
```

keep in mind, I am not stripping outside quotations, as it seems that those are used by the executable. If not, then change to:

```
@echo off
(echo %~1&echo %~2&echo %~3&echo %~4)|bil.exe
```

As you never need to set anything in relation to the variable name, we simply do not use variables as they come as input meta variables from your input.